# Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Let Me Type My Password and Log in

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, password

When I turn on my laptop, everything seems to boot normally and I enter my decryption key to decrypt my hard drive. Then I'm taken to my login page, but when I try to type in my password, none of my keys work and I can't move my mouse. Why is this happening?

NOTE: Earlier, I had a problem where I would get a black screen of death whenever I turned on my laptop and I resolved this by going into recovery mode and reinstalling Nvidia drivers. Now, I have the problem mentioned above and whenever I go into the root terminal in recovery mode, I find that I'm not able to install any packages. I can't even do a simple apt-get update.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> ) and type:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The text editor will open and you should change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

As follow:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Please note: You may unable to enter Ubuntu environment, therefore you can choose recovery mode for booting up. So, you will be able to do these modifications easily.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you can enter your password just fine. The password does not show up in the terminal when you type it even '*' will not be shown, but that is for security reasons. Just try typing your password out, and hitting enter. If your password was entered correctly, the action will continue. If your password was spelled wrong, it will prompt you to enter it again.