# Can't login after sleep/CTRL+ALT+F1 - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. I installed version 18.04 in dual boot with grub.

**Problem**

I've been having problems logging back after it's been asleep. When I open the lid and get to the the login screen (user choice), most of the times the trackpad and keyboard do not respond. When this happens, I cannot click on my user name and log in, can't even get to the password prompt. I can't do anything. Only thing I can do is a manual restart.

I've been troubleshooting the problem for a little while now.
I have tried solutions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032594/keyboard-not-responding-after-waking-up-from-suspend-ubuntu-18-04), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067301/ubuntu-18-04-wont-let-me-type-my-password-and-log-in), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep). None work, the problem still occurs.

**Solutions tried**

- Setting my grub file to

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
  ```

  messes up the resolution and then I can't change it.
- Any other combination for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` as stated in the previous links
- Also, while looking at other threads, I have found that i'm supposed to be able to switch between consoles and the GUI when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd>. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, it takes me back to the login screen where I can't enter anything! Trackpad and keyboard do not work at this point (nor any combination of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd>). I have to do a manual restart. I believe this is related to the problem I have after the computer wakes from sleep.
- I have also updated the kernel from 4.15 (i think) to 4.20.15 without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Specs**

My laptop is an ASUS UX360CA with touchscreen. I don't know if the fact that the screen can change orientation based on how the laptop is placed has an impact but that setting is locked (off) anyway.

```
[~]$ uname -r
4.20.15-042015-generic
[~]$ lsb_release -r
Release:    18.04
[~]$ lscpu
Architecture :                          x86_64
Mode(s) opératoire(s) des processeurs : 32-bit, 64-bit
Boutisme :                              Little Endian
Processeur(s) :                         4
Liste de processeur(s) en ligne :       0-3
Thread(s) par cœur :                    2
Cœur(s) par socket :                    2
Socket(s) :                             1
Nœud(s) NUMA :                          1
Identifiant constructeur :              GenuineIntel
Famille de processeur :                 6
Modèle :                                78
Nom de modèle :                         Intel(R) Core(TM) m3-6Y30 CPU @ 0.90GHz
Révision :                              3
Vitesse du processeur en MHz :          600.012
Vitesse maximale du processeur en MHz : 2200,0000
Vitesse minimale du processeur en MHz : 400,0000
BogoMIPS :                              3024.00
Virtualisation :                        VT-x
Cache L1d :                             32K
Cache L1i :                             32K
Cache L2 :                              256K
Cache L3 :                              4096K
Nœud NUMA 0 de processeur(s) :          0-3
Drapaux :                               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp flush_l1d
```

Comment: Did you a clean install? Have you done update, upgrade, dist-upgrade after install properly? Did  you install gdb3 Gnome desktop? You said that trackpad and Keyboard do not respond. Please go to `settings` and check the status of those peripheral devices.

Comment: Please do one experiment. Go to `settings` and `privacy` and `disable` screen lock. Your laptop won't go to `sleep`. Verify @mikibok, this has any impact on login.

Comment: How to reach peripheral devices? Go to `settings`, `devices` and you will see `keyboard`, `Mouse & Touchpad` along with others.

Comment: You said that your laptop has dual-boot. Did you observe any problems to login Windows-10? Could you access BIOS setup screen by pressing `del` key? Did you see the presence of two boot loaders (one for windows and the other for Ubuntu)? Did you set default boot loader on your GRUB menu? What is your default Boot loader at present in your GRUB menu?

Comment: In response to your comments @Marmayogi. 
The status of the trackpad and keyboard are fine in the `settings`. However, I cannot check this when the problem occurs. I have done update, upgrade without any changes. _I will try dist-upgrade_. I do have gdm3. I also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` without any luck. The problem does not occur when I am on Windows. There are two boot loads and by default it is on GRUB 2.02. _I will also try to disable the screen lock_. If all else fails, _I will try a clean install_. 
Thanks for your help!